# How to view the deleted object in active directory

Tags: active-directory, admin

Can you just tell me, how to view the deleted objects in active directory without administrator login. Otherwise please tell me which ACEs can I use to view those deleted objects.

Answer (score 4):

To view the deleted objects stored on an Active Directory domain controller:

1. Start Ldp.exe, and then click Connect on the Connection menu. Type the server name of a domain controller in the enterprise, verify that the Port setting is set to 389, click to clear the Connectionless check box, and then click OK. After the connection is established, server-specific data is displayed in the right pane.
2. On the Connection menu, click Bind. Type the user name, password, and domain name (in DNS format) in the appropriate boxes (you may need to click to select the Domain check box), and then click OK. If the binding is successful, you should receive a message similar to "Authenticated as dn:'YourUserID'" in the right pane.
3. On the View menu, click Tree. Type the distinguished name (DN) of the domain in the Base DN box. The base DN is the starting point in the Active Directory hierarchy at which searches begin. In the Base DN box, type
     dc=,dc=
     replacing  and  with the appropriate domain name.

   This generates a tree view in the left pane beginning with the DN you typed. Double-click the root node of the tree view and in the right pane, locate the data associated with the "wellKnownObjects" attribute. Look for the line associated with the "Deleted Objects" data. For example, this may look like:
     B:32:18E2EA80684F11D2B9AA00C04F79F805:CN=Deleted
     Objects,DC=YOURDOMAIN,DC=COM
4. Copy all the data following the second colon but before the third colon. For example:
     18E2EA80684F11D2B9AA00C04F79F805
5. On the Browse menu, click Search. In the Base DN box, type
     `<WKGUID=18E2EA80684F11D2B9AA00C04F79F805,DC=YOURDOMAIN,DC=COM>`
     replacing "18E2EA80684F11D2B9AA00C04F79F805" with the value you copied in the previous step.

   NOTE: The starting and ending "<" and ">" characters are very important.
6. In the Filter box, type:
     (objectClass=*)
7. Click Options, and then click Controls. In the Object Identifier box, type:
     1.2.840.113556.1.4.417
8. Clear the Value box, set the Control Type to Server, click to clear the Critical check box, and then click Check in >>. Click OK.
9. In the Search Call Type section of the dialog box, click Extended and check the state of the following check boxes:
     Attributes Only - cleared
     Chase referrals - cleared
     Display Results - selected
     Set "Size Limit:" to a sufficiently large value such that all the deleted objects in the directory can be returned by the query. LDP will return up to the number of objects specified in "Size Limit:", and if there are more objects that cannot be returned, it will log an error. The error returned in the right-hand pane is:
     Error: Search: Size Limit Exceeded. <4>
     If you experience this error, set the "Size Limit:" higher and execute the Search again.

   If necessary, modify the timeout value from zero to 60000 milliseconds.

10 . Click OK to close the Search Options dialog box, click Subtree in the Scope box, and then click Run.

same INFORMATION AVAILABLE ON http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258310

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question can be found in [kb892806](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/892806). In short:

> To modify the permissions on the
>   deleted objects container so that
>   non-administrators can view this
>   container, use the DSACLS.exe program.
>
> To grant a security principal
>   permission to view the objects in the
>   deleted objects container, type a
>   command that is similar to the
>   following example: dsacls "CN=Deleted
>   Objects,DC=Contoso,DC=com" /g
>   CONTOSO\EricLang:LCRP
>
> In this example, the user
>   "CONTOSO\EricLang" has been granted
>   List Contents and Read Property
>   permissions on the deleted objects
>   container in the "CONTOSO" domain.

Comment: You probably want to just add the LO (list objects) permission. If you do anything else, you are probably creating an unintended security hole in your directory.

Think of CN=Deleted Objects as a common "recycle bin". By granting "Read Property" to the Deleted Objects container you are granting read-rights to the object data for *any* object that gets deleted, whether or not the current user had permission to view that object in its original location. The object ACLs are persisted in CN=Deleted Objects, so by granting ListObject only, you are preserving the existing security scheme.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward method is to use LDIFDE tool when you have a large database and being tired of dealing with the 'get-adobject' timeout. So basically, use LDIFDE to list all deleted objects in "CN=Deleted Objects"

Ldifde -x -d "CN=Deleted Objects,DC=Your,DC=Domain" -d deletedobj.ldf

And if you want also an easy way to count how many objects are in recycled bin just do this

(LDIFDE -x -v -d "CN=Deleted Objects,DC=Your,DC=Domain,DC=com" -f deleted.ldf)|Select-String -Pattern "entries exported"

Hope it helps!